# Where to find subtle border patterns?

Tags: website-design, patterns, borders

Is there any border pattern version to the website http://subtlepatterns.com/?

What I mean is that these patterns are usually used not as backgrounds but just as a border or divider between two sections. Although I can use some from Subtle Patterns, they're more geared to be used as backgrounds and not as a one line pattern.

Comment: I think you are over complicating things.  You may need to re-focus on your creativity, take a break and look at it in a different angle.  Reason why I say this is because I've never seen someone before tell me a pattern was geared for only X purpose and couldn't be used for anything else other than as a background.

Comment: I'd suggest editing this question to be about "How do I apply a pattern to a border / stroke?"

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how that Photoshop plug-in works, but If you asking for Photoshop workaround, following may be helpful

1. you could create your own patterns and save them.
2. then you can use "Stroke" layer effect
3. then select "Fill Type" --> "Pattern"
4. Select pattern which you created/wish to act as border/divider.